# SwiftUI ScrollView scrolled past element with .id()

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is there any way to be notified when `ScrollView` was scrolled past element that was given some ID?

For instance:

```
@State var selectedFoodTypeId: UUID? = nil

HStack {
    ForEach(foodTypes) { foodType in
        Text(foodType)
            .foregroundColor(selectedFoodTypeId == foodType.id ? .red : .black)
    }
}

ScrollView {
    ForEach(foodTypesAndRestaurants) { item in
        Text(item.foodType)
            .id(item.foodType.id)
        
        // When ScrollView was just scrolled here, I would like to do the following:
        // withAnimation {
        //      selectedFoodTypeId = item.foodType.id
        // }
        
        ForEach(item.restaurants) { restaurant in
            Text(restaurant)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `.onAppear(perform: { })` or  `.onDisappear(perform: {})` with additional logic.

---

```
Text(item.foodType)
  .id(item.foodType.id)
  .onAppear(perform: { })
```